# Gridview RowUpdating can't find a control

Tags: vb.net, gridview, findcontrol

As the title says I am unable to find the control I want.

This is the GridView:

```
    <asp:GridView ID="gvInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AutoGenerateEditButton="true">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="filename" HeaderText="Filename" SortExpression="filename" />
            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="Button" CommandName="Select" 
                HeaderText="Move File" ShowHeader="True" Text="Move File" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
```

This is the code behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If Not IsPostBack Then
        ShowGV()
    End If
End Sub

Protected Sub gvInfo_RowEditing(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewEditEventArgs) Handles gvInfo.RowEditing
    gvInfo.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex
    ShowGV()
End Sub

Protected Sub gvInfo_RowCancelingEdit(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewCancelEditEventArgs) Handles gvInfo.RowCancelingEdit
    gvInfo.EditIndex = -1
    ShowGV()
End Sub

Protected Sub gvInfo_RowUpdating(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles gvInfo.RowUpdating
    Dim row = gvInfo.Rows(e.RowIndex)
    Dim Test As String = CType(row.FindControl("filename"), TextBox).Text
    Response.Write(Test)

    gvInfo.EditIndex = -1
    ShowGV()
End Sub
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
CType(row.Cells(0).Controls(0), TextBox).Text
'change index of `cell(0)` to required column index (column index starts from 0)
```

or

convert required column to a `TemplateField` and use,

```
CType(row.FindControl("LabelNamein'EditItemTemplate'"), TextBox).Text
```

Comment: The first bit just returns ""

With the second bit what do you mean by TemplateColumn?

Comment: @Rambomst Sorry about the incorrect answer. I have updated it now, first method should work.

Comment: TemplateColumn : http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/data-access/custom-formatting/using-templatefields-in-the-gridview-control-cs